# Which ROS version will be appropriate for an Autonomous Underwater Vehicle?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot has to complete specified tasks underwater.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117616/which-ros-version-will-be-appropriate-for-an-autonomous--underwater-vehicle-?/) by [Shiva Saxena](https://answers.ros.org/users/10816/shiva-saxena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the current one unless there is a specific package that you want to use that's not available any more.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4